# Python - Matplotlib, plot constant field

Tags: python, matplotlib, field

I would like to plot a constant field but it s not very beautiful...
its value is zero and i want a colorbar between -1 and 1!
I try that with :

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

plt.rcParams['text.usetex']=True
plt.rcParams['text.latex.unicode']=True

Lx=80.
Ly=120.
x0 = 30.
y0 = Ly/2.

YA, XA = np.mgrid[0:Ly, 0:Lx]

Order0 = 0*np.ones((YA.shape[0], YA.shape[1]))

plt.imshow(Order0,aspect='auto',cmap=plt.cm.hot,origin="lower")
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cax = ax.imshow(Order0, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.hot)
ax.set_title(r"\ test",fontsize=20)
plt.axis('off')

cbar = fig.colorbar(cax, ticks=[-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1])
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(['-1', '-0.5', '0','0.5' ' 1'])# vertically oriented colorbar
plt.show()
```

[image]

I would like to get an image like this in order to respect other results :

Comment: I know it s special to plot a constant field but it s to show the result of orders in a series... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want to change the line:

```
plt.imshow(Order0,aspect='auto',cmap=plt.cm.hot,origin="lower")
```

to add vmin and vmax:

```
plt.imshow(Order0,aspect='auto',cmap=plt.cm.hot,origin="lower", vmin=-1, vmax=1)
```

giving:

[image]

Comment: Thanks it s what i want. But in order to respect the "frame" of my work, i would like to delete the grid of axis so i add : "plt.axis('off')" and i would like to respect the same colorbar which gives only 1., 0.5, 0., -0.5 and -1, i try with "cbar = fig.colorbar(cax, ticks=[-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1])
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(['-1', '-0.5', '0','0.5' ' 1'])" but dont work in this case :/

Comment: i add an image to see what i said

Comment: Notice that you have two plots, so you have two plt.show(). Before the first one you have *not* added the plt.axis('off') or the cbar line... If you still find errors when you add them to the FIRST plot, you could update the question to include this additional remark and put the updated code, so we can take a closer look.